# Do static properties end up living in gen2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, static, garbage-collection

When I have a `static` field/property which lives in my application pool for the life of the application pool, where does it live in memory?  I'm assuming its promoted into `gen2` and lives out its days there? (assuming its small enough not to go into the [LOH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static properties live in the heap *in the memory space allocated to* the **type object** for the type/class. They are loaded at the same time the type is loaded.

Static properties cannot be garbage collected. Type object can never be unloaded.

End of the chapter 4 of the book [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) explains it. Here is a small snippet diagram:[image]

This is just a portion of the diagram (cannot copy fully because of the copyright) and shows `Employee` type object with its static fields. Type object is similar to all other objects and has a pointer to its type which happens to be `System.Type`.

Comment: Thanks for that, the reason I'm asking is that when we used ants memory profiler we founds some static field values in gen2. When change them from being static to non static and ran the profiler again, only to discover they were no longer in gen2. With your answer I'm now not sure what is going on.. :S

Comment: Well,I would not be that surprised to see them in gen2 although I would know hey cannot be garbage collected. At the end of the day, if they belong to a root object, they cannot be garbage collected, which what gen2 is.